# Join Four Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I looked and tried various examples, but still not get the results I need.

With have a table called "item" which has metadata about media (books, vidoes, mp3 ,etc"

and a table "item_format" with the URL of the video

and  Table with "categories"

and a relational to called "categories_item"

I want to find all the record on our youTube videos sorted by categories. so that if you look for "parenting"  we get list a list a youTube and the title.

```
parenting   https://youtube/v/K8cJKirMo-A     Love is The Tey  
            https://youtube/v/uodqINpEC_w     Discipline  
            https://youtube/v/Ko-ZboCzR64     Become Her Friend
```

and so on, listing all the categories assigned

item.media-type LIKE '%video%'

```
 item
===============
item_id       media_type             title 
1             video/teachings        Discipline
2             video/news             December Update
3             video/landscape        Quad Copter Noni Field

 item_format
=================
item_format_id         item_id         format
1                      2               https://youtube/v/K8cJKirMo-A
2                      4               https://youtube/v/uodqINpEC_w

 category
=================
category_id         item_id      name 
1                      2         parenting     
2                      4         ethics  

  category_item # the bridging table between item/category
=================
category_item_id   category_id  item_id
1                      2           2         
2                      4           3
```

I tried things like this but get errors, frankly out my depth here

```
select item.title, item_format.format
  from item i
    left join item_format if
      on i.item_id = if.item_id
    left join category_item ci
      on i.item_id = ci.item_id
    left join category c
      on ci.category_id = category_id
  where i.media_type LIKE '%video5' 
  order by c.name
```

I can't get to first base

Unknown column 'item.title' in 'field list' #line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query is ok , but a small change need. you use table alias. in first line just use table alias instead of table name

```
select i.title, if.format,c.name
from item i
left join item_format if on (i.item_id = if.item_id)
left join category_item ci on (i.item_id = ci.item_id)
left join category c on (ci.category_id = c.category_id)
where i.media_type LIKE '%video5' 
order by c.name
```

Comment: You forgot the shift key in LIKE  '%video5'  But after that is worked!

Answer (score 1):

you have to provide alias once you have given it:

see if it works:

```
select i.title, if.format,c.name
  from item i
    inner join item_format if
      on i.item_id = if.item_id
    inner join category c
      on i.item_id=c.item_id 
    inner join category_item ci
      on c.category_id=ci.category_id
  where i.media_type LIKE '%video%' 
  order by c.name
```

or this:

```
select i.title,if.format,c.name
from item i,item_format if,category c, category_item ci
where 
i.item_id=if.item_id and
i.item_id=c.item_id and
c.category_id=ci.category_id
order by c.name;
```

Comment: The use of `,` for `JOIN` was made obsolete a very long time ago.

Comment: Yes, but as it's no longer part of the standard that is not guaranteed for the future. And it really makes queries a lot less readable.